# Как открыть папку на android в проводнике или галерее

Tags: java, android

Вывожу список папок в Android надо открывать папки в проводнике Android. Проводник то открывает, но совсем не ту папку а дефолтную uri - правильный что оно хочет, то же самое если ACTION_VIEW ставить дефолтная папка, путь не учитывается

```
  public void openFile2(Uri uri) {
      Intent openLinkIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

      openLinkIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
      openLinkIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);

      String type = AppFileManager.mime(uri.toString());
      if(type != null)
          openLinkIntent.setDataAndType(uri, type);
      else
          openLinkIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
      try {
          startActivity(openLinkIntent);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          L.i("бида");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Насколько мне известно никак. Есть только возможность открывать папку при создании документа.